# Django admins disappearing from the admin index

Tags: django, admin

We're running a Django website with rough 45 install Django admin classes. The handler is mod_fastcgi. Every once in a while about half the admins disappear from /admin/ screen. Touching the production.fcgi file restores everything to normal, but we have yet to determine the underling cause.

Any thoughts on what the underlying issue might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django turns off admin for the model when it encounters an exception in admin. Examine admin code and make proper exception handling.